# Oracle Convert Rows to Columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

I have folowing Dataout put from my query

```
**Date**    **HIGH**  **LOW**       **IMAGE**      **TYPE**
1/28/2012     69         42          1.jpg           SUN
1/29/2012     70         42          2.jpg           MSUN
```

I want to Convert this Output into

```
**1/28/2012**       **1/29/2012**
1.jpg                    2.jpg    
Sun                       MSUN
69                         72  
42                         42
```

Here is My query

```
SELECT 
   W_DATE,HIGH, LOW, 
   W_TYPE, IMAGE
FROM WEATHER
ORDER BY W_DATE ASC
```

And Also I have multiple dates in rows i want to display only 4 dates and they should change when system date is chanaged

Comment: Are you asking how to make the actual result from Oracle look like this?  Or how to take the result set from Oracle and display it differently in your own program's output (e.g. an HTML page)?

Comment: Yes I want to display on aspx page in Gridview Control with images

Comment: You should mention that in the question so it's clear what you're asking about.  (I added an asp.net tag to the question just now.)

Comment: O Sorry for that So How can I Do this

Answer (score 0):

About all the possibilities how get from rows to columns in oracle you can read up here:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

I don't see a straight forward solution for that from database point of view - would suggest to do the formatting on application side, otherwise it could look as lame as this:

```
SELECT
   to_char(w1.w_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_char(w2.w_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
   to_char(w3.w_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_char(w4.w_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM 
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate)) w1,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 1) w2,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 2) w3,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 3) w4
UNION ALL
SELECT
   w1.image,  w2.image, w3.image , w4.image
FROM 
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate)) w1,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 1) w2,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 2) w3,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 3) w4
UNION ALL
SELECT
   w1.w_type,  w2.w_type, w3.w_type , w4.w_type
FROM 
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate)) w1,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 1) w2,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 2) w3,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 3) w4
UNION ALL
SELECT
   to_char(w1.high),  to_char(w2.high), to_char(w3.high) , to_char(w4.high)
FROM 
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate)) w1,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 1) w2,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 2) w3,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 3) w4
UNION ALL
SELECT
   to_char(w1.low),  to_char(w2.low), to_char(w3.low) , to_char(w4.low)
FROM 
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate)) w1,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 1) w2,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 2) w3,
 (select * from weather where w_date = trunc(sysdate) + 3) w4;
/
```

Comment: An answer from Tom Kyte might also be of use: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:5331044584595759::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4031849343543#11288826016365