# convert rows to columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle Convert Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043152/oracle-convert-rows-to-columns)

I have the below senario.

I will get account data every week and I have to maintain a table which contains the 100 week history in columns (there are lot business logics involved lets not mind it as of now)

eg: my input files are

week 1:

```
Key1 key2 value
1     1    100
1     2    200
```

week 2:

```
1     1    100
1     3    300
```

week 3:

```
1     1    100
1     2    200
1     3    300
```

the target should be

```
key1 key2  week1 week2 week3
1     1     100   100   100
1     2     200   null  200
1     3     300   300
```

Rules:

1. the week the record comes is the starting week for the record(week1)
2. there onwards the presence or absence need to be recorded.

note: the record volumes are very large so cannot perform some random update and joins

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions on here, search for one of them.

Comment: There's more to this question than just pivoting rows into columns.  I suggest the OP needs to expand this question with some additional info.  For instance, is the data kept in files or loaded into tables.  How many weeks' worth of data do they start with?  What happens whne Wekk 101 rolls round?

Comment: You are right APC. the date is loaded from file to table.. we can use any temp table we need. the target holds 104 weeks data.. wen we reach 105th week the 1st week data is removed and overwritten by 2nd week 2nd by 3rd..

Comment: eg: take a sample of 3 weeks 1 2 3 when data comes for 4th week it will be 2 3 4